# Role-Based Access Control - RBAC YII V1 ORACLE

Tags: php, oracle, yii, pdo, authorization

I am developing an application with yii v1 and oracle database, when I want to use RBAC (checkAccess), I get the following error:

> CDbCommand falló al ejecutar la sentencia SQL: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1405 OCIStmtFetch: ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL
>   (/tmp/pdo/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:446). The SQL statement executed was: SELECT *
>   FROM "AUTHITEM"
>   WHERE NAME=:NAME

the tables are already up 
how I can fix this?
any ideas?

thank's in advance!

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36974

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a problem with pdo_oci driver, you can avoid this error by using this extensión Yii's [PHPPDO extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/phppdo/). Extract it under **protected/extensions** then at **protected/config/main.php** add the following stuff to your DB connection:

```
db'=>array(
      'class'=>'application.extensions.PHPPDO.CPdoDbConnection',
      'pdoClass' => 'PHPPDO',
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ali has given link to the bug fix, you get `Oracle NULL` which is not convertable into `php NULL`.

> pdo_oci does not convert oracle nulls to php nulls when fetching from lob fields.

So, i'd recommend to first do a NULL check and based on the result do request for roles:

SELECT * FROM  WHERE `NAME` IS NULL OR `NAME`=''

Another option is to fetch data using the AR `findBySQL()` method using in it the `NVL()` Oracle function.

The third option i'd think is to restrict your roles db table to NOT NULL values.